# VHDL Error: Net is driven by multiple primitive gates

Tags: vhdl, precision

I've been trying to write some code for a lab i need to do this week but ran into the error mentioned in the title (image below). The code just needs to cycle new inputs through 4 registers and checking to see which is the largest and smallest of the set. The following code is what I was using when i got the errors;

```
 library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity max_min is
    port( 
     din : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     reset : in std_logic;
     clk : in std_logic;
     sel : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
     max_out : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     min_out : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
     reg_out : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
     );
    end max_min ;

    architecture arch of max_min is
    signal R0,R1,R2,R3 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    begin
        --Reset and register cycle
        process(clk,reset)
        begin
            if(reset = '1') then
                R0 <= "1000";
                R1 <= "1000";
                R2 <= "1000";
                R3 <= "1000";
                max_out <= "0000";
                min_out <= "0000";
            elsif(clk'event and clk = '1') then
                if(R0 /= din) then
                    R3 <= R2;
                    R2 <= R1;
                    R1 <= R0;
                    R0 <= din;
                end if;             
            end if;
        end process;
        --Greater Than logic
        process(clk)
        begin           
            if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
                if(R0 >= R1 and R0 >= R2 and R0 >= R3) then
                    max_out <= R0;
                elsif(R1 >= R0 and R1 >= R2 and R1 >= R3) then
                    max_out <= R1;      
                elsif(R2 >= R0 and R2 >= R1 and R2 >= R3) then
                    max_out <= R2;  
                elsif(R3 >= R0 and R3 >= R1 and R3 >= R2) then
                    max_out <= R3;  
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
        --Less Than logic
        process(clk)
        begin           
            if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
                if(R0 <= R1 and R0 <= R2 and R0 <= R3) then
                    min_out <= R0;
                elsif(R1 <= R0 and R1 <= R2 and R1 <= R3) then
                    min_out <= R1;      
                elsif(R2 <= R0 and R2 <= R1 and R2 <= R3) then
                    min_out <= R2;  
                elsif(R3 <= R0 and R3 <= R1 and R3 <= R2) then
                    min_out <= R3;  
                end if; 
            end if;
        end process;    
        --Register Select
        process(clk,sel)
        begin
            if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
                case sel is
                    when "00" =>
                        reg_out <= R0;
                    when "01" =>
                        reg_out <= R1;
                    when "10" =>
                        reg_out <= R2;
                    when "11" =>
                        reg_out <= R3;
                    when others =>
                        reg_out <= "0000";
                end case;
            end if;
        end process;    
    end arch;
```

The following is the set of errors i got when running the above code in Precision RTL;

[image: **The Errors**]

I'm not very experienced with VHDL yet, so i'm not sure what these errors mean or what i may have done wrong. The code didn't seem to have any errors when i ran it through Modelsim.

Comment: The error messages pretty much tell you : the signal in question has multiple drivers. Perhaps you are driving it in more than one process? Don't do that...

Comment: @Brian Drummond Wait so a signal can only ever be used in a single process?

Comment: DRIVEN in a single process. Unless you take some special measures which aren't relevant here. It can be used (read) in any number of processes. Think hardware : you have shorted two outputs together here.

Comment: You can easily combine all processes in one process. And you should label the processes. And don't use `std_logic_unsigned`. Use `numeric_std` and actually use `unsigned` types.

Comment: I know it can probably be compressed down to one process, but the manual says "The VHDL must contain at a minimum two clocked processes: one for the 4 registers comprising
the shift register organization, and another for the max/min output registers. You may use one
clocked process for each of the output register for a total of 3 clocked processes.." I tried to follow that as best I could, but the comments i'm getting seem to conflict with this requirement.

Comment: Your synthesis tool expects a synthesis eligible subset of VHDL which doesn't include a separate process for reset. Some Mentor documentation is only available to those eligible for support making it hard for a third party to point out where you can look. It's otherwise valid but not useful VHDL code, multiple processes assigning signals creating multiple drivers that are resolved in package std_logic_1164. Comment out the min_out and max_out assignments in the first process. An image doesn't a [mcve] make and the personal pronoun I is capitalized in English.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had max_out and min_out in two separate processes. Once i merged them all into one process it fixed itself.

Thank you to all the commenters for their advice.